# Unity UNET - A Server (Not Host) is calling [ClientRpc]s on itself

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have a NetworkManager started in Server Mode, using [StartServer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.StartServer.html), not Host

Before any clients connect, I set my code to do this:

```
public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        base.OnStartServer ();
        Debug.Log("// "  + name + " has netId: " + netId + "  assetId: " + GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().assetId);
        InvokeRepeating ( "RpcCall", 2.0f, 10.0f );
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    public void RpcCall()
    {
        Debug.Log ( "// " + name + " Client called by server OK.  NetId: " + netId );
    }
```

I expected that to fail, Because ClientRpc calls should only happen on Clients, not the server (unless it is a host)

This is explained [here](http://ClientRpc%20calls%20are%20sent%20from%20objects%20on%20the%20server%20to%20objects%20on%20clients.) and I had just taken it to be true.  Am I setting something up wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realised the answer while writing - UNET does not work if you use Invoke or InvokeRepeating.  It will call the function locally no matter what you set it to.